# Move Logo Without Changing Design

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a logo I created using a div and two letters which I want to move inside the coral colored div. However every time I change left/right properties or margin/padding I end up changing the letter placement in the design.

I tried playing around with the CSS using developer tools but I'm still having trouble.

Is there a better way I could use to move the logo itself and maybe make it a big smaller inside the coral div? This is what I'm trying to do [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acd7B.png). *note: screenshot is from Figma but I'm trying to code what it looks like

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <!--  Faustina-->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Faustina' rel='stylesheet'>
    <!-- Didact Gothic -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Didact Gothic' rel='stylesheet'>
    <!-- Encode Sans Semi Condensed -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Encode Sans Semi Condensed' rel='stylesheet'>
    <!-- Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="parent">

      <!-- Description -->
      <div class="description">
        <div class="d">DESCRIPTION</div>
      </div>

      <!-- Logo -->
      <div class="logo">
        <div class="logo-container">
          <div class="box">
            <div class="letter-c">C</div>
            <div class="letter-p">P</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Navigation -->
      <div class="tabs">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Projects</li>
            <li>Blog</li>
            <li>Resume</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <!-- Icon -->
      <div class="icon"> </div>

      <!-- Contact-Footer -->
      <div class="contact">
        <footer>
          <div class="icon-container"> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" class="linkedin-icon">
              <!--! Font Awesome Pro 6.1.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2022 Fonticons, Inc. -->
              <path d="M416 32H31.9C14.3 32 0 46.5 0 64.3v383.4C0 465.5 14.3 480 31.9 480H416c17.6 0 32-14.5 32-32.3V64.3c0-17.8-14.4-32.3-32-32.3zM135.4 416H69V202.2h66.5V416zm-33.2-243c-21.3 0-38.5-17.3-38.5-38.5S80.9 96 102.2 96c21.2 0 38.5 17.3 38.5 38.5 0 21.3-17.2 38.5-38.5 38.5zm282.1 243h-66.4V312c0-24.8-.5-56.7-34.5-56.7-34.6 0-39.9 27-39.9 54.9V416h-66.4V202.2h63.7v29.2h.9c8.9-16.8 30.6-34.5 62.9-34.5 67.2 0 79.7 44.3 79.7 101.9V416z" /></svg>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 496 512" class="github-icon">
              <!--! Font Awesome Pro 6.1.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2022 Fonticons, Inc. -->
              <path d="M165.9 397.4c0 2-2.3 3.6-5.2 3.6-3.3.3-5.6-1.3-5.6-3.6 0-2 2.3-3.6 5.2-3.6 3-.3 5.6 1.3 5.6 3.6zm-31.1-4.5c-.7 2 1.3 4.3 4.3 4.9 2.6 1 5.6 0 6.2-2s-1.3-4.3-4.3-5.2c-2.6-.7-5.5.3-6.2 2.3zm44.2-1.7c-2.9.7-4.9 2.6-4.6 4.9.3 2 2.9 3.3 5.9 2.6 2.9-.7 4.9-2.6 4.6-4.6-.3-1.9-3-3.2-5.9-2.9zM244.8 8C106.1 8 0 113.3 0 252c0 110.9 69.8 205.8 169.5 239.2 12.8 2.3 17.3-5.6 17.3-12.1 0-6.2-.3-40.4-.3-61.4 0 0-70 15-84.7-29.8 0 0-11.4-29.1-27.8-36.6 0 0-22.9-15.7 1.6-15.4 0 0 24.9 2 38.6 25.8 21.9 38.6 58.6 27.5 72.9 20.9 2.3-16 8.8-27.1 16-33.7-55.9-6.2-112.3-14.3-112.3-110.5 0-27.5 7.6-41.3 23.6-58.9-2.6-6.5-11.1-33.3 2.6-67.9 20.9-6.5 69 27 69 27 20-5.6 41.5-8.5 62.8-8.5s42.8 2.9 62.8 8.5c0 0 48.1-33.6 69-27 13.7 34.7 5.2 61.4 2.6 67.9 16 17.7 25.8 31.5 25.8 58.9 0 96.5-58.9 104.2-114.8 110.5 9.2 7.9 17 22.9 17 46.4 0 33.7-.3 75.4-.3 83.6 0 6.5 4.6 14.4 17.3 12.1C428.2 457.8 496 362.9 496 252 496 113.3 383.5 8 244.8 8zM97.2 352.9c-1.3 1-1 3.3.7 5.2 1.6 1.6 3.9 2.3 5.2 1 1.3-1 1-3.3-.7-5.2-1.6-1.6-3.9-2.3-5.2-1zm-10.8-8.1c-.7 1.3.3 2.9 2.3 3.9 1.6 1 3.6.7 4.3-.7.7-1.3-.3-2.9-2.3-3.9-2-.6-3.6-.3-4.3.7zm32.4 35.6c-1.6 1.3-1 4.3 1.3 6.2 2.3 2.3 5.2 2.6 6.5 1 1.3-1.3.7-4.3-1.3-6.2-2.2-2.3-5.2-2.6-6.5-1zm-11.4-14.7c-1.6 1-1.6 3.6 0 5.9 1.6 2.3 4.3 3.3 5.6 2.3 1.6-1.3 1.6-3.9 0-6.2-1.4-2.3-4-3.3-5.6-2z" /></svg>
          </div>
        </footer>

      </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 0px;
    grid-row-gap: 0px;
  
  }
  /****************************************************************/

   /* Logo */
  .logo {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
    background-color: lightcoral;
  }

  .logo-container {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    top: 56px;
  }
  
  .letter-c {
    position: absolute;
    width: 31px;
    height: 63px;
    left: 26px;
    top: 8px;
  
    font-family: 'Faustina';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 63px;
    /* identical to box height */
    color: #DEC3C3;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px white;
  }
  
  .letter-p {
    position: absolute;
    width: 27px;
    height: 66px;
    left: 47px;
    top: 29px;
  
    font-family: 'Didact Gothic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 66px;
    /* identical to box height */
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  
  .box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background: #DEC3C3;
  }

  /****************************************************************/

  /* Navigation */
  .tabs {
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 6;
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 20px;
  }
  
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    font-family: 'Encode Sans Semi Condensed';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
  }

  /****************************************************************/

  /* Description */
   .description {
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 5 / 3;
    background-color: red;
  
  }

  /****************************************************************/

  /* Icon */
  .icon {
    grid-area: 2 / 3 / 5 / 6;
    background-color: lightblue;
  }

  /****************************************************************/

  /* Contact-Footer */
  .contact {
    grid-area: 5 / 1 / 6 / 6;
    background-color: lightseagreen;
  }
  
  svg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    color: #DEC3C3;
  }
  
  footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 620px;
    top: 942px;
  }
  
  .icon-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
  
    background: rgba(222, 195, 195, 0.2);
    border-radius: 30px;
  }
  
  .github-icon {
    left: 132px;
    bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  .linkedin-icon {
    left: 42px;
    bottom: 10px;
  }
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following changes to `.logo-container {...}`:

- Inside `.logo-container {...}`, include `position: relative` (to make absolute postioning of `.box` with respect to it, work). Then remove the `margin`, `left` and `right` values.

  - The `margin` property isn't necessary in `.logo-container` since it will cue its margins from the grid placement of its parent `.logo`.
  - The `left` and `right` properties aren't needed as well for the same reason as above (and also since, setting `position: relative` produces defaults of `top: 0` and `left: 0`); remember, you are trying to position the `.box` div which houses the letters, not `.logo-container` itself. You should rather position `.box` from its own rule set.

If you need padding around `.logo-container` set it within its parent: `.logo`

Here's what `.logo-container` rule should look like:

---

```
.logo-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px; 
}  

.box {
    // Position me (w/ margin, left and right) from here instead 
    // if you wish to. 
} 

.logo {
    ...
    // put padding around .logo-container here.
}
```

And Voilà! Problem fixed!

If you want the `.parent` div to take the full height of the viewport (i.e screen), you may set `height: 100vh` in its CSS rule:

---

```
.parent {
    ...
    height: 100vh;
 }
```

Alternatively (much better way):

---

```
 html,
 body {
     height: 100%;
 }

.parent {
     height: 100%;
 }
```

If you need to remove browser default box-sizing, margin and padding properties, then add this rule set at the top of your CSS file or section:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```